# What is a good web based graph visualizer?

Tags: web-applications, graph, data-visualization

I am looking to create a WEB BASED graph with the option different sized nodes. I know that GraphViz can be used for static images, but are there any easy to use frameworks or tools to create an INTERACTIVE graph?

I am trying to make something where you can browse the nodes of a graph online. (With options like changing node size and color, etc)

(I know JUNG can do something similar, but the animation is not too smooth and I don't think you can click on the actual nodes for interactivity.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Prefuse](http://prefuse.org/) does web-based animated interactive graphs really well.

Answer (score 0):

[Scott Guthrie's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/02/07/built-in-charting-controls-vs-2010-and-net-4-series.aspx) talks about them for ASP.NET

Comment: You are referring to charts, the question relates to graphs.